# why is the sum of size of NVMe disk partitions are less than actual size of NVMe disk?

Tags: partitioning, disk, fdisk

I am trying to write a script which verifies the size of disk. So I thought I can get the total size of NVMe and add up all the size of partitions done on that disk. If both the values match, then I can say that size of disk is correct. But in this process, I figured out that the sum of size of partitions done on nvme drive will not be equal to the total available size of nvme. The sum of partitions will be slightly less than the total size.

Is there any other way to verify the size of disk through a script? Like comparing the reference value with the output of `fdisk -l` or `lsblk`? How do I get the reference value?

Below is an instance:
When I add the size of all partitions (size of /dev/nvme0n1p1 + size of /dev/nvme0n1p2 +....) Total size of all the partitions in NVME is 255961081151 bytes, but the actual size of /dev/nvme0n1 256060514304 bytes.

Sample log:

```
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
```

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E8FB91BA-B2CF-A14D-AE9B-75943FA10290

```
**Device                      Start                     End         Sectors                  Size                      Type**
/dev/nvme0n1p1              17094664            500118143          483023480          247308021760                Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p2              22533                   55300                   32768                   16777216                ChromeOS kernel
/dev/nvme0n1p3              8706056              17094663            8388608              4294967296                ChromeOS root fs
/dev/nvme0n1p4              55301                   88068                   32768                   16777216                ChromeOS kernel
/dev/nvme0n1p5              317448                 8706055              8388608              4294967296                ChromeOS root fs
/dev/nvme0n1p6              16448                   16448                   1                            512                       ChromeOS kernel
/dev/nvme0n1p7              16449                   16449                   1                            512                       ChromeOS root fs
/dev/nvme0n1p8              88072                   120839                 32768                   16777216                Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p9              16456                   18503                   2048                     1048576                Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p10            18504                   18504                   1                            512                       ChromeOS reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p11            64                          16447                   16384                   8388608                unknown
/dev/nvme0n1p12            251912                 317447                 65536                   33554432                EFI System
```

And the delta is not fixed.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **;-)** What is the output of `lsb_release --release` and `uname --kernel-release`?

Comment: $lsb_release --release
Release:        18.04
$ uname --kernel-release
4.15.0-54-generic

Comment: Looks like a Chrome OS / Windows machine to me.

Comment: yes it is chrome book.